# Multiple 4K videos in a GStreamer / QML app = black flickering

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer, flicker, blink

I'm developping a QML application allowing to display up to four 4K videos, with a Decklink 8K Pro and the qmlglsink element.

The hardware setup is the following:

- 4 4K cameras
- 1 DeckLink 8K Pro
- 1 Dell Precision with 2 Intel Xeon E5-2698 (40c/80t), 256GB of memory and an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080

When displaying the 4 videos at the same time in my app, I frequently have black frames (I see a black flash and then the video is back). When displaying 3 videos, blinks are much less frequent, and I don't think I've seen them when showing only 1 or 2 videos.

A few interesting things:

- if I start 4 instances of Gstreamer with one 4K video in each, there's no blink
- if I start 4 instances of my app with one 4K video in each, there's no blink
- say I'm showing 2 times camera A and 2 time camera B (I also have some hardware to duplicate video streams). When a blink occurs, it does for the two video views of that camera (A or B).

It looks to me like a threading problem, but adding a queue element to my pipeline does not fix the problem. Setting QSG_RENDER_LOOP to threaded with qputenv doesn't either.

Is there anything else I can do?

Here's some code used to create the pipeline:

```
// Create the source element (see below for the makeElement method):
GstElement* decklink_src = VideoView::makeElement("decklinkvideosrc", { {"device-number", 0}, {"mode", "2160p2997"}, {"profile", 4} });

// Create the pipeline element (see below for the generatePipeline method):
GstElement* pipeline = generatePipeline(_source, m_videoViewItem->findChild<QQuickItem*> ("videoView"));

// Schedule rendering:
m_window->scheduleRenderJob(new SetPlaying (m_pipeline), QQuickWindow::BeforeSynchronizingStage);

GstElement* VideoView::makeElement(const std::string& _elementName, const std::map<std::string, QVariant>& _params)
{
    GstElement* element = gst_element_factory_make(_elementName.c_str(), nullptr);

    for(const auto& attribute : _params)
    {
        const char* name = attribute.first.c_str();

        switch (attribute.second.type())
        {
            case QVariant::Type::Int:

                g_object_set (element, name, attribute.second.toInt(), nullptr);
                break;

            case QVariant::Type::String:
                gst_util_set_object_arg (G_OBJECT(element), name, attribute.second.toString().toStdString().c_str());
                break;

            default: break;
        }
    }

    return element;
}

GstElement* VideoView::generatePipeline(GstElement* _src, QQuickItem* _parent)
{
    GstElement* pipeline = gst_pipeline_new(nullptr);

    GstElement* queue = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", nullptr);
    GstElement* glupload = gst_element_factory_make ("glupload", nullptr);
    GstElement* glcolorconvert = gst_element_factory_make ("glcolorconvert", nullptr);
    GstElement* sink = gst_element_factory_make ("qmlglsink", nullptr);

    g_assert (_src && queue && glupload && glcolorconvert && sink);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN (pipeline), _src, queue, glupload, glcolorconvert, sink, nullptr);
    gst_element_link_many(               _src, queue, glupload, glcolorconvert, sink, nullptr);

    g_object_set(sink, "widget", _parent, nullptr);

    return pipeline;
}
```

Comment: I can post my suggestion in form of code but man, is that elaborated, I cannot remember what the other Stack* forum is for that? And still it sounds almost like *work* and not necessarily helps you (no idea of how exactly the video rendered and suggest big rework?). Please consider this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html and this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html Simply put we are dealing with some Qt QML deficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the links, there are a few suggestions I can try. I'll also try a fixed layout (currently videos can be drag 'n dropped). The rendering is done by GStreamer. If you want to have a look, it happens in the QtGLVideoItem::updatePaintNode method of qtitem.cc (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/ext/qt/qtitem.cc), and in GstQSGTexture (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/ext/qt/gstqsgtexture.cc). A bit hard to understand if you are unfamiliar with Gstreamer.

Comment: While I am not using QtGLVideoItem but my *educated* guess is that you need to stage multiple pending OpenGL updates till QQuickWindow::beforeRendering signal. That should minimize the flicker. I am familiar with GStreamer but still did not use those.

Comment: @AlexanderV, thanks. I reduced my QML to the minimum and tried a few suggestions of your links with no change. I guess the problem lies in the qmlglsink element itself, I'll open a ticket at GStreamer's GitLab.

Comment: For the reference, here's the GStreamer ticket: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/issues/648#note_222693